# Ubuntu touch full desktop

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, desktop-environments, unity-greeter

Would it be possible to take my nexus 10 with the latest ubuntu for tablets installed, mount the system partition as rw, and, by means of adding and removing packages, get a full unity 7 desktop working? Please explain why or why not.